# Camel Jetty response is Object ID instead of XML generated by JAXB

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel

I am working on an Apache Camel project. Basically the Jetty endpoint takes a Http Post request and the message goes through a few steps of transformation in the route. The last step of transformation is through JAXB, which converts Java object into XML. The Java DSL is below

```
final DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("sample");
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/foo")
.unmarshal(format).split(body()).marshal(jaxb)
```

My problem is that when I send a POST request to the localhost URL, the HTTP response is string
**[sample.Claims@b68e0e]**, not the XML I expected. This is the JAXB object ID. When I changed the DSL to

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/foo")
.unmarshal(format).split(body()).marshal(jaxb).to("stream:out")
```

I can see the XML print out correctly in the stdout. I don't know how to make the HTTP Response to contain XML instead of the Object ID. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

I want to clarify what I try to accomplish. **I need to convert a delimited string to an xml document**. The post message to Jetty endpoint is a delimited string. The route first uses BeanIO to convert the string into a POJO and the POJO into XML using JAXB. Even though the post message is a single line string, I have to use split() because BeanIO by default dealing with multi-line flat file. I followed @Peter's suggestion by adding aggegate after the jaxb marshaling as below

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/transformProxy/ECSProxy")
.unmarshal(format).split(body()).marshal(jaxb)
.aggregate(constant("1"),new MyAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(1).to("stream:out");
```

but it does not seem to make any difference. I still get [sample.Claims@1a631c2] as the Http response body, while the stdout prints out the correct xml document. I am not sure how/when the response body of the jetty endpoint is set.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `convertBodyTo(String.class)` after the marshalling to XML?

Comment: The body is split into single parts but the splits are not aggregated. Perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: @Ralf I tried the converBodyTo method and it does not help. The result is still objectId. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the response. I added the aggregate after the marshal(jaxb) as marshal(jaxb).aggregate(constant("1"),new MyAggregationStrategy()).completionSize(1).to("stream:out"). The problem is the same. The stdout prints out the right xml, while Jetty response only shows [sample.Claims@1a631c2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by moving the aggregate strategy as the second parameters of the split.  For details, please see https://camel.apache.org/splitter.html. Search for the "**Split aggregate request/reply sample**"